# Ember js: Why does the action not get fired?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm a noob in EmberJS. I have created an app using ember-cli.

**Use Case**: I want to have navigation with two menus: Home Admin. Admin has sub menus: Users Organizations. On clicking Users, /users route and on clicking Organizations /organizations route should fire. This is what I have done.

In the `application.hbs file`, I have the following line:

```
{{view 'main_menu'}}
```

this is the `app/views/main_menu` file:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
var MainMenu = Ember.CollectionView.extend({

  tagName: 'ul',
  classNames: ['nav', 'top-nav-menu'],
  content: function () {
   var result = [];
   result.push({label: "Dashboard", routing: 'dashboard', active: 'active'},
               {label: "Admin", routing: 'admin'});

  return result;

  }.property(),


 itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
   classNameBindings: ['active', ':top-nav-dropdown'],
   active: function(){
      return this.get('content.routing').indexOf('dashboard') === 0 ?"active":""; 
      return "";
    }.property(),
   templateName: 'main_menu',

    dropdownMenu: function () {
      var item = this.get('content').routing;
      var itemsWithDropdown = [ 'admin'];
      return itemsWithDropdown.contains(item);
    }.property(''),

    isAdminItem: function () {
      console.log("Inside is admin item");
      return this.get('content').routing == 'admin';
    }.property(''),


     dropdownCategories: function () {
      var itemName = this.get('content').routing;
      var categories = [];
      // create dropdown categories for each menu item
      if (itemName == 'admin') {
        categories = [];
        categories.push({
          name: 'users',
          url: 'users/',
          label: "Users"
        });
        categories.push({
          name: 'organizations',
          url: 'organizations/',
          label: "Organizations"
        });
      }
      return categories;
    }.property(''),

 AdminDropdownItemView: Ember.View.extend({
    // console.log("inside admin drop down item view");
     tagName: 'li',
     classNameBindings: 'isActive:active'.w(),
     isActive: function () {
       console.log("Inside the is active function");
       return this.get('item') === this.get('parentView.selectedAdminItem');
      }.property(),

      goToCategory: function (event) {
         console.log("inside admin drop down item view");
 /*I'm just printing something here to make sure control comes here before I proceed coding*/
       }
 })
})

});

export default MainMenu;
```

This is the app/templates/main_menu.hbs file:

```
<a href= {{view.content.routing}} > 
  {{{unbound view.content.label}}}
</a>

{{#if view.isAdminItem}}
  <ul class="top-nav-dropdown-menu">
    {{#each category in view.dropdownCategories}}
      {{#view view.AdminDropdownItemView item="category.name" }}
        <a href="#" {{action "goToCategory" category.url target="view"}}>{{category.label}}</a>
      {{/view}}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
{{/if}}
```

All other actions get called but the action goToCategory does not get called. Nor does it give error in the console that no action handler written as it usually gives one.

Comment: Views should not be used. They are to be considered an internal part of Ember. I believe either Yehuda or Tom said this in one of their EmberJS presentations. Instead, use components.

Comment: I agree views are unnecessary in this context. I actually followed an app i had for reference. Basically the question along with how should i achieve my objeCtive also is why the action does not get fired

Comment: Try adding 'goToCategory' in an actions object in the view. like actions: {goToCategory: function........}

Comment: @blessenm: You were the first to help in this way, put it as an answer so that I can mark it.

Comment: I see @rog already put the answer. Ill get the next one. :)

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that.  Just saw the question and answered w/o reading comments here.  @blessenm, if you post your answer I'll delete mine.

Comment: @rog its ok. +1 for being polite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put your actions in a hash called `actions`:

```
AdminDropdownItemView: Ember.View.extend({
  ...
  actions: {
    goToCategory: function (event) {
      console.log("inside admin drop down item view");
    }
  }
})
```